# Confusion about width of absolute positioned div

Tags: html, positioning, css-position, css

Since my confusion is better understood when looking at it, I created a fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qQS92/3/. Think of it as a tree structure.

The red and blue div obviously don't have the same width, although I expect them to. What prevents the blue div from using all the width it needs to display the text? I want it to break at the same places the red div breaks.

Here's another fiddle that animates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QPFw8/6/
It seems that the problem is the width of the root div. Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by using `right:80px` instead of `left:-80px`.

The problem comes because the right side of the red div is fixed to the right side of the parent. Which happens to be 0px wide, and located 120px to the left of the page.

[Edit]

Oh, your problem was the other way around. In that case you need to use `right:-80px` instead of `left:80px` on the blue div.

[/Edit]

Comment: Thanks. This looked promising but if you try to apply this on the animated example (which has more in common with the real case), than the problem appears on the other side. I have the impression that this will not be solvable with CSS alone.

Comment: That's because the animation unfortunately only sets the css `left` property. If you want the animation to work with right, you will need to roll your own.

Answer (score -2):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` style to #right div.

Comment: Okay, while this circumvents the problem for the demo, I cannot use this since I also want to set a max-width on the children, so that the text eventually wraps. Sorry, I didn't mention that earlier, I will update the example.

Comment: You have set the maximum width of child div to 60px. So how do u expect that its contents dont wrap?!

Comment: If we "Add white-space: nowrap; style to #right div.", our text will be shown as a long one line. It's not suitable.